# Javascript event file retrieval

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I'm currently having a problem with events in Javascript. I'll first try to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to draw a canvas based on the contents of a file retrieved in the `<input type="file" />` element. I was trying to do an OOP based design for this.

I want to create a widget that can do this.

So first, I have created my widget class:

```
Dicom5.Rendering.Viewer = function(){
    var viewer = document.createElement('div','dicom5-rendering-viewer');
    
    var fileOpener = new Dicom5.Rendering.FileOpener();
    var canvas = new Dicom5.Rendering.Canvas();
    
    
    viewer.appendChild(fileOpener.render());
    viewer.appendChild(canvas.render());
    
    this.render = function(){
        return viewer;
    }
};
```

I also have the following two classes `FileOpener` and `Canvas`

```
Dicom5.Rendering.Canvas = function(){

    var canvas;
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    this.render = function(){
        return canvas;
    }
};
```

and the fileOpener

```
Dicom5.Rendering.FileOpener = function(){
    
    
    var fileOpener = document.createElement('input');
    fileOpener.setAttribute('id','dicom5-rendering-fileopener');
    fileOpener.setAttribute('type','file');
    
    fileOpener.onchange = function(){
       **HERE !! I want to change my canvas object**
    }
     
    
    this.render = function(){
        return fileOpener;
    }

};
```

So as you can see I have one object, that has a `Canvas` object and a `FileOpener` object. I want to change the instantiated Canvas object with the instantiated `FileOpener` object. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to keep them un-coupled and have `Viewer` glue them together. Perhaps `FileOpener` could provide a callback (e.g., event) for when it needs to update the `Canvas`, and `Viewer` could pass in a handler for that callback and do the actual work. I said "callback," but it can be more of an event or `Observer` model, so one `FileOpener` could have multiple handlers for the event that needs to update `Canvas`.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking something of that. Do you perhaps know an example online where I can read something about this?